# Is there any way to pass params between task in tekton?

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have two different tasks which I want to pass the `taskRun` name of the first task to the second task. I wonder if there is a way I can do that.

Answer (score 3):

The `taskRun` name is available as a [variable](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/variables/#variables-available-in-a-task) and you can emit it as a [task result](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/tasks/#emitting-results) in your first Task.

Then you can use the *result* from a previous task as input parameter to the next task. See [Passing one Task’s Results into the Parameters or when expressions of another](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#passing-one-task-s-results-into-the-parameters-or-when-expressions-of-another).

That should solve it.